# using css, add a subtitle below a title

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to add a subtitle below the title on my page. I've got an image to the left of the existing title, and the title is centered to the middle of the image. I'm trying to add a subtitle in a smaller font below the title and I can't seem to figure it out. The code I'm using is like so:

```
<div class="top_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container">
<img src="images/grin.png" WIDTH="150" ALT="BRT" />
<div class="text">This is the Title</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>  
</div>
</div>


.container {
display:table;
width:100%;
height:auto;
background-color:#171717;
}
.container .text {
display:table-cell;
height:100%;
vertical-align:middle;
font: bold 70px Verdana;
color: #666666;
}
```

and here's what that looks like: [image]

(I'm not including the code for the menu even though it's in the picture).

And what I'm trying to achieve is this:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Pseudo elements should not contain actual content..surely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `div.text` which contains your title. Underneath that you need to place your subtitle. This code is called "html markup". You should use `<h1>` - `<h6>` tags for titles.

Here is an example ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKfRm/))

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
}
.header img {
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/000000/fff" />
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h2>This is a subtitle</h2>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[You can in fact do this with CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/333g4/)

```
div.text {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 2px 1em;
}

div.text:after {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    content: "This is the subtitle";
}
.container {
    background-color: #111;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now, whether you *should* do that with CSS is another question entirely. Content that's actually part of your page's message should be part of the page, not part of a style sheet.

Also, your "container" should probably be an `<h1>` tag. Also you don't need to close `<img>` tags, and self-closing tags are pointless in an HTML5 document (which yours may or may not be I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="top_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container">
<img src="images/grin.png" WIDTH="150" ALT="BRT" />
<div class="text">This is the Title</div>
<div class="subtitle">My subtitle</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>  
</div>
</div>

.text {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.subtitle {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably 100 different ways to do this...  Here's one. In your line of text, just use a `<br />` and a `<span>`

```
<div class="text">This is the Title<br /><span>The SubTitle would go here</span></div>
```

Then style your subtitle like so:

```
.container .text span {
    /* Something styled here */
}
```

Comment: unsure why this is downvoted - this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

The html your using could be improved as it is not really appropriate. 
Try something like this

```
<div class="header">
<img src="images/grin.png" WIDTH="150" ALT="BRT" />
<h1>this is the title</h1>
<h3>This is the subtitle<h3>
</div>  


.header{
overflow:hidden
}

.header img {
float:left;
}

.header{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Sergio S. That worked for me. A more *general* way of doing this, based on Sergio's answer (is the following):

```
CSS:
.classofheadertext {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.classofsubtitletext {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Full credit once again to Sergio. I've just put this in simple form :D

Comment: Thanks are nice. Up arrows are nice too.